# Import pfx certificate to azure key vault

Tags: azure, azure-keyvault, pfx

I'm trying to import a pfx certificate to the azure key vault, but I'm getting an error saying that no certifcate with private key was found.

I'm using the ImportCertifcateOptions, not sure if "certificate.RawData" is the way to go.

This is the code that I'm using

```
var certificate = new X509Certificate2(
            localFilePath, 
            password, 
            X509KeyStorageFlags.Exportable);

        if (!certificate.HasPrivateKey)
        {
            throw new BusinessException("No private key included");
        }

        var importOptions = new ImportCertificateOptions(name, certificate.RawData);
        var azureKeyVaultCertificate = await CertificateClient.ImportCertificateAsync(importOptions);
```

This is the error that I'm getting from azure.

*No certificate with private key found in the specified X.509 certificate content. Please specify X.509 certificate content with only one certificate containing private key.
Status: 400 (Bad Request)*

Comment: How did you create the certifcate/pfx file?

Comment: I tested with 2 differents certificats that was sent to me, that actullay I've succesfully installed manually in azure key vault.

Comment: can you import thr PFX file from the portal?

Comment: @MichaelHoward-MSFT yes, I can import/export that certificate from the portal, and I can use it at my AppService using Azure.Security.KeyVault.Certificates.CertificateClient